# What condition to check in wait() in while loop?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning multi-threading programming in Java, and the most difficult part seems to be inter-thread communication, using `wait()`, `notify()` and `notifyAll()`.

I referred to official Javadoc of `wait()` , reproducing here:

```
 synchronized (obj) {
     while (<condition does not hold>)
         obj.wait();
     ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
 }
```

I got the point that when a thread `t` calls `wait()` it immediately releases the lock and then waits; however I am not able to understand what the condition in `while loop` means? Can't there be a chance before thread `t` checks for the condition in `while loop` the condition has been modified by some other thread?

Can anyone tell me what this `condition` is and what basic things are to be used in `while` loop for checking the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not able to understand what the condition in while loop means?

Literally, it means the logical inverse of the condition that you are waiting to happen.

> Can't there be a chance before thread t checks for the condition in while loop the condition has been modified by some other thread?

The assumption<sup>1</sup> is that the variables that make up the "condition" are only updated by another thread *while it is holding the lock on `obj`*.

Hence, at the point immediately after the while loop, the thread in the code above knows that the condition is now true, and nothing else will change it before it releases the lock.

Now ... obviously ... if some other thread is going to change the variables that make up the condition *without* holding the lock, then what you are worried about *can* happen.  But that's a buggy program.  You have shared variables being updated by different threads without adequate<sup>2</sup> synchronization.

---

<sup>1 - The thread has to be holding that lock when it calls `obj.notify()` or `obj.notifyAll()`.  (If not, you will get an exception.)  But the guarded condition will also work if the variables are updated in a separate synchronized block to the notify call.  It just makes the code harder to understand ...</sup>

<sup>2 - In this context, declaring variables as `volatile` is not sufficient for correct behavior of the guarded condition.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to understand in general, what are "those" conditions for which we have to do the "looping" for the wait()? Can you please share some information?

Comment: They are ... basically ... whatever you are waiting for.  Maybe it is waiting for a value to be available, for a counter to reach zero, for space to be available in a queue or buffer, ...

Answer (score 2):

You need not only to loop it but check your condition in the loop. Java does not guarantee that your thread will be woken up only by a notify()/notifyAll() call or the right notify()/notifyAll() call at all. Because of this property the loop-less version might work on your development environment and fail on the production environment unexpectedly.

For example, you are waiting for something:

```
synchronized (theObjectYouAreWaitingOn) {
   while (!carryOn) {
      theObjectYouAreWaitingOn.wait();
   }
}
```

An evil thread comes along and:

theObjectYouAreWaitingOn.notifyAll();
If the evil thread does not/can not mess with the carryOn you just continue to wait for the proper client.

Edit: Added some more samples. The wait can be interrupted. It throws InterruptedException and you might need to wrap the wait in a try-catch. Depending on your business needs, you can exit or suppress the exception and continue waiting.

check below one also for your better clarity.

wait and notify are used to implement [condition variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Blocking_condition_variables) and so you need to check whether the specific predicate you're waiting on is true before continuing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `obj` might call all waiting threads up by `obj.notifyAll()`, these woken up threads will enter syncronized code block in an uncertain order, and operate the shared data. So, it is necessary to check condition in `while` loop.

Suppose you have an empty queue, thread1 and thread2 is waiting to take element from it,

```
 synchronized (obj) {
     while (queue.isEmpty())
         obj.wait();
     ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
     queue.take();
 }
```

After thread3 putting an element in this queue, and calls `obj.notifyAll()`, which will call thread1 and thread2 up:

- thread1 wakes up first, find the only element in queue, and take it.
- thread2 wakes up later, check if there is any element in queue by `queue.isEmpty()`, and `wait()`
  again.

Answer (score 1):

The `condition` in the head of a `while` loop can be any expression which resolves in a `boolean`.

In your example the `while` loop should suspend the execution of the real method until a certain condition is `true`.

Let's assume your `synchronized` method needs to be executed at 12pm and needs thread-safe access to the object `obj`

Then you head of the `while` loop would check if the current time is NOT 12pm. If this is `true`, the method cannot start it's real work. But to prevent blocking resources it will allow other threads to work with `obj` by calling `obj.wait()`.
When we reach 12pm the condition of the `while` loop will be `false` and the thread exists the `while` loop and execute the rest of your code.